# Schedule Later - Check version/status of page published - AEM/CQ

Tags: adobe, aem

AEM provides a OOTB functionality to Activate Later. Following the scenario where confusion is happening

1. User Schedules a page for Activate Later (suppose 5 mins after current time). It internally creates a page version and waits for selected time.
2. User modifies some content in the page. In /siteadmin console, modified timestamp is updated and modified icon is changed to "Blue".
3. Now Schedule Later workflow publishes the version created in step 1 to publish instance (Changes done in step 2 are not published, which is fine and is expected behavior), Replicate API creates another version while replicating in case of content change.
4. After the page is published /siteadmin console shows "Green" icon status under published column. But "Blue" icon under modified column is removed.

Now this creates a bad user experience (Not sure if this is a bug in AEM, the status under modified column should have been Blue, which would give feedback to author that currently page is in modified state and published version is older). My question is, is there a way to verify which version of page from author instance is currently present in publish instance (So that at least we can be sure that modified version is not yet published). Or control the modified column in /siteadmin console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AEM has a so called [Timewarp](https://docs.adobe.com/content/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/wcm/page_create_edit.html#Using%20the%20Timewarp%20Calendar) feature, this allows you to see the publishing activities for a page.